# Delete strings in a vector

Tags: c++, string, vector

I have a vector full of strings

the vector consistentWords contains 4 strings

1. dedf
2. eedf
3. fedf
4. hedf

Now I want to delete all the strings that words don't start with the letter d

However it ends up just deleting eedf and hedf and the result I have left is

1. dedf
2. fedf

My code:

```
    for(int q=0; q<consistentWords.size(); q++)
    {
        string theCurrentWord = consistentWords[q];
        if(theCurrentWord[0] != 'd')
        {
            consistentWords.erase(consistentWords.begin()+q);
        }
    }
```

Any thoughts? I just can't see why it's not deleting all of the strings that don't start with d.

Comment: You may want to make `theCurrentWord` a reference to avoid copy.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are deleting elements from the vector and incrementing your index `q` in the same iteration. So in the 2nd iteration of your for loop, you erase `"eedf"` from you vector then your vector is `["dedf", "fedf", "hedf"]` and `q = 1`. But then when you loop back to the begining of the for loop, `q` is incremented to 2 so you look at `"hedf"` next, skipping `"fedf"`. To fix this you could decrement `q` when you remove an element from the array like so:

```
for(int q=0; q<consistentWords.size(); q++)
{
    string theCurrentWord = consistentWords[q];
    if(theCurrentWord[0] != 'd')
    {
        consistentWords.erase(consistentWords.begin()+q);
        --q;
    }
}
```

Or you could use iterators:

```
vector<string>::iterator it = consistentWords.begin()
while(it != consistentWord.end())
{
    string theCurrentWord = consistentWords[q];
    if(theCurrentWord[0] != 'd')
    {
        it = consistentWords.erase(it);
    }
    else
    {
        ++it;
    }
}
```

Note that `erase` returns an iterator to the element after the one you have erased. You must re-assign `it` because it becomes invalidated when the vector is resized.

Answer (score 3):

You are skipping elements. Assume you need to delete elements 5,6:
when you delete element 5, element 6 becomes element 5 - and you skip it, since `q` was increased to 6,

The better way to do it is manually increasing `q` only when you do not delete an element

Comment: Even with iterators we have to be careful. As I recall when you delete from a vector the iterator accessing the element becomes invalid.

Comment: Be careful deleting elements in a vector or map while iterating through it.  A correct algorithm is non-obvious, and usually has several subtleties.

Comment: thanks for the comments. I removed the "iterator" part from the answer.

Answer (score 3):

To start with, the strings correspond to these indices:

```
dedf 0
eedf 1
fedf 2
hedf 3
```

Let's say you delete `eedf` (so `q == 1`. After the delete, the vector looks like

```
dedf 0
fedf 1
hedf 2
```

But then `q` gets incremented to 2, completely skipping over `fedf`. The fix would be to alter the `for` loop slightly:

```
for(int q=0; q<consistentWords.size();)
{
    string theCurrentWord = consistentWords[q];
    if(theCurrentWord[0] != 'd')
    {
        consistentWords.erase(consistentWords.begin()+q);
    }
    else
    {
        q++;
    }
}
```

or something to the same effect.

Answer (score 2):

When you erase you should not do q++. Then you miss one element.

Answer (score 2):

The question has been answered, but you should look into the [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

Example:

```
consistentWords.erase(
    std::remove_if(consistentWords.begin(), consistentWords.end(), 
    [](const std::string& s) -> bool { return (s[0] == 'd'); }),
    consistentWords.end());
```

Answer (score 0):

To remove the word:

```
consistentWords.erase(
    std::remove(consistentWords.begin(), consistentWords.end(), theCurrentWord),
    consistentWords.end()
);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can't wrap your head around all the other answers about indices and skipping one, then really you could create a new vector and then copy it back, or just use a deque.

**New Vector Approach:**

You go through each string in your original vector. If it starts with 'd', then add it to the new vector. And your answer is the new vector. If you want the original vector to have the data, then just copy it back.

```
    vector <string> newVec;
    for (int q = 0; q < consistentWords.size(); ++q) {
        if (consistentWords[q][0] == 'd') {
            newVec.push_back(consistentWords[q]);
        }
    }
//if needed, copy back with simple code at this point
```

**Deque Approach:**

You change the vector into a deque and go through each string as usual. If it starts with 'd', then add it to the back, looping until you finish. And your answer is the original deque.

```
    deque <string> consistentWords;
    bool first = true;
    string firstStr;
    for (int q = 0;;) {
        if (consistentWords[q][0] == 'd') {
            if (consistentWords[q] == firstStr) {
                break;
            }
            if (first == true) {
                first = false;
                firstStr = consistentWords[q];
            }
            consistentWords.push_back(consistentWords[q]);
        }
        else {
            consistentWords.pop_front();
        }
    }
```