# c++, stl. Remove a concrete value from vector<string>?

Tags: c++, string, vector, stl, std

for example:

```
vector<string> strs;
strs.push_back("1");
strs.push_back("2");
strs.push_back("3");
strs.push_back("4");
strs.push_back("3");

//strs.removeAllOccurencesOfValue("3");
```

I found this example:

[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9121532/delete-strings-in-a-vector)

but are there any easier ways? For example using boost framework?

Comment: I'm sure there are some existing [algorithm](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm) to [remove](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove) values from collections.

Comment: [`std::remove`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/remove). In particular, see the example.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a perfectly fine [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom):

```
#include <algorithm>

strs.erase( std::remove(strs.begin(), strs.end(), std::string("3")), strs.end() );
```

Comment: thanks, my mistake is I used remove_if instead of remove. Usually predefined "remove" function/method means deleting a concrete range, not a concrete value

Comment: @user2083364 `remove_if` would work here, too, but you'd need to specify a comparator.

Comment: I meaned I used the it the similar way as you used remove and this was my mistake

Answer (score 1):

*Scott Meyers* talks about the [Erase-remove idiom](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Erase-remove_idiom) in his *Effective STL: 50 Specific Ways to Improve Your Use of the Standard Template Library*. It seems perfect for your case:

```
#include <algorithm>    // for std::remove

vector<string> strs;
strs.push_back("1");
strs.push_back("2");
strs.push_back("3");
strs.push_back("4");
strs.push_back("3");

strs.erase( std::remove( strs.begin(), strs.end(), "3" ), strs.end() );
```